# Laravel Blade: calling property in object results in NULL

Tags: php, json, laravel, object, laravel-blade

I'm using blade to display a package. The package contains some options which are true or false. However, when I try to access those options using blade, it returns NULL. This is the full JSON object `$item`:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Budget Pakket","created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","script_options":[{"id":1,"name":"CMS","price":506,"parent_id":null,"type_id":3,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":1,"included":1}},{"id":2,"name":"Foto Album","price":481,"parent_id":null,"type_id":2,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":2,"included":1}},{"id":3,"name":"Parallax Images","price":643,"parent_id":null,"type_id":1,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":3,"included":1}},{"id":4,"name":"Meerdere Menus","price":868,"parent_id":null,"type_id":3,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":4,"included":1}},{"id":5,"name":"Logo Design","price":370,"parent_id":null,"type_id":1,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":5,"included":0}},{"id":6,"name":"Deadline","price":179,"parent_id":null,"type_id":2,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":6,"included":0}},{"id":7,"name":"Thema Op Maat","price":146,"parent_id":null,"type_id":3,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":7,"included":0}},{"id":8,"name":"Thema Kant-en-Klaar","price":390,"parent_id":null,"type_id":1,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":8,"included":1}},{"id":9,"name":"Bulk Email","price":311,"parent_id":null,"type_id":1,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":9,"included":0}},{"id":10,"name":"Layouts","price":497,"parent_id":null,"type_id":1,"created_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","updated_at":"2018-03-05 20:38:36","pivot":{"package_id":1,"script_option_id":10,"included":1}}]}
```

So, as far as I know, this should work to display the `script_options`:

```
{{ $item->script_options }}
```

I've also tried to iterate through them using these lines of code:

```
@foreach($item->script_options as $option)
    <tr>
        {{ $option }}
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

But for some reason it gives NULL back....

### EDIT

I retrieved the result with

```
$result = Package::with('scriptOptions')->get();
return view('package.index', compact('result'));
```

And after that I iterate through the 3 results using this:

```
@foreach($result as $item)
    ......
@endforeach
```

### EDIT 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `{{ dd($result) }}` on top of your blade file to see if $result have data in it.

Comment: I've displayed the result in the edit. The Data is all fine

Comment: Have you updated the column from `script_options` to `scriptOptions`?

Comment: show me response of `{{ dd($item->script_options) }}`

Comment: That can't be done of course on the top of the page. However, I've used `{{ dd($result[0]->script_options) }}` to get the result you want, and that return `null`